# redirection inside and outside command substitution

Tags: bash

Why can't the following redirection outside the command substitution suppress the output to stderr:

```
OLD_DATE=$(date --date"three days ago")  2> /dev/null
```

while this one with the redirection inside the command substitution can:

```
OLD_DATE=$(date --date"three days ago" 2> /dev/null)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems because **the redirect applies to the *empty* command after the assignment.** For example, you get the same result with this command:

```
OLD_DATE=$(date --date"three days ago") true 2> /dev/null
```

And this is the same as your command without the assignment:

```
2> /dev/null
```

(Yes, that's a valid command line.)